# How does having more threads work with NServiceBus?

Tags: nservicebus

If you buy the enterprise version of NServiceBus, you can have have more than one thread.

I am not sure what this means.

Here is what I hope it means:

If you have 4 threads, then your `Handle` method will fire 4 times then wait for one of the calls to finish, then fire again (with a new message).

We have not purchased the full version yet, so I have no way to test if this is how it really works.

Can anyone who has used the full version enlighten me?

(Note I am on NServiceBus 2.6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 4 messages in your queue, and 4 threads, then all 4 messages will be processed at the same time.